# Обращение к великому человеку по имени

Tags: грамотная-речь

Однажды на паре музыкальной литературы (или: "по музыкальной литературе"?) преподаватель, анализируя моё сочинение, сделала следующее замечание: "Владимир, вы обращаетесь к великому человеку по имени. Он что, вам приятель, друг? Обязательно употребляйте фамилию". Действительно, я много раз говоря о Шумане, чтобы избежать повторений, обращался только к его имени: "Роберт решил основать журнал", "Роберт относился к младшему поколению романтиков" и т. д. С тех пор я осторожничаю. Но! Сейчас ссылок привести не смогу, но в авторитетных источниках, в частности в худ. литературе, встречаю такое обращение к гению по имени. Так что, я ошибался и проявлял фамильярность?

Comment: Роберт решил, Роберт относился... Это надо называть обращением?

Comment: ОБРАЩЕНИЕ, Толковый словарь Ушакова: https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/894542 :)

Comment: А как выразиться иначе? Упоминание гения?

Comment: *А как выразиться иначе?* - ***"Именование"***. Можно и "упоминание" - по контексту. Да в принципе-то "обращение", "обратиться" нельзя считаь грубой ошибкой, у "обращения" есть близкое к нужному значению: "В своей работе Имяреков обращается к трудам Аристотеля". "И тогда он обратился к Богу (вере)" и проч. Другое  дело, что в устах учителки прозвучало двусмысленно.

Comment: === все сказанное не означает, что сам вопрос я считаю заслуживающим право на существование. Это область, которую регулируют правила эьткета, далекие от собственно языковых. Да и этикетные правила тут трудно применить без контекста.

Answer (score 0):

Моё мнение: если ваша училка такая нервенная, выражайтесь при ней иначе. А в принципе нет абсолютно ничего плохого в том, чтобы называть Шумана Робертом.

Вот против «Боба» я бы возражал :)